# Match duplication of the uploaded PDF document?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, pdf, file-upload, paperclip

I am looking at for preventing the duplication of the same pdf document with one of my application.

I know it's quite an easy task along with the name of the document but, I don't want to match the PDF duplication by its name.

Here the challenge comes, I want to check the duplication of the uploaded document based on the contents, not by the name of the document uploaded by the end user.

I have never prevented with such scenario in past but want to know, If someone has a way to get resolved my problem.

You solution or tricks will be really helpful.

Thanks in Advance and waiting for a wondering solution with the same.

Comment: It depends on your definition of duplicate. Is a PDF with the exact same visual contents but different internal Metadata a duplicate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way is to generate checksum from uploaded file, store in the database (or some other place) and then check if checksums for new uploaded files are already present in the database.

In Ruby you can use `Digest` module to do that:

```
require "digest"
data = File.read("some_file_path")
checksum = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(data)
```

You don't have to check for filename, just use this checksum.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to look by MD5 checksum. Instead of reading or parsing files line by line, generate MD5 digests for them and match. Those with same MD5 values are same files.

How to generate MD5 for a file in Ruby?

```
require 'digest'
Digest::MD5.file("path/tp/pdf").hexdigest
# md5 string
```